# Use value in Excel cell as condition for WHERE clause in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

```vb
Sub Get_Data()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim dateVar As Date

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=bi; UID=username; PWD=password; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

                strSQL = " SELECT " & _
                            " Products " & _
                            " FROM Logistics " & _
                            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ""2020-02-24"" " & _
                            " GROUP BY 1"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

    Sheet5.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

I run the above `VBA` to extract values fom the `database`. 
It works exactly how I need it.

---

Now, instead of having a pre-defined date within `strSQL` I want to use the data that is entered into `Cell B1` in my Excel spreadsheet. Therefore, I changed the `strSQL` part in the `VBA` to:

```
        strSQL = " SELECT " & _
                    " Products " & _
                    " FROM Logistics " & _
                    " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = " & Sheet1.Range("B1") & " " & _
                    " GROUP BY 1"
```

However, now I get `runtime error -2147217887 (80040e21)` on  `rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic`.

What do I need to change in my `VBA` to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
strSQL =    " SELECT " & _
            " Products " & _
            " FROM Logistics " & _
            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = '" & Format(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "' " & _
            " GROUP BY 1"
```

Just be aware, if `insert_timestamp` does indeed contain a ***time*** other than midnight, you might not get the results you're after without converting to just a date or altering your SQL.

Comment: Thanks. Exaclty what I needed.

Comment: Any idea for this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639194/use-date-in-excel-cell-in-between-clause-in-sql-query

Answer (score 3):

Consider the industry best practice of [SQL parameterization](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) using the [ADO Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) object which can properly handle data types without string concatenation or various formatting:

```vb
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection      ' REMOVE New INITIALIZATION IN Dim LINES
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim dateVar As Date

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; ..."
conn.Open

' STRING STATEMENT WITH QMARK PLACEHOLDER
strSQL = " SELECT " & _
             "   Products " & _
             " FROM Logistics " & _
             " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) = ?" & _
             " GROUP BY Products"

' CONVERT CELL TO DATE TYPE (IF CELL FORMATTED AS STRING)
dateVar = CDate(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value)

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
   .ActiveConnection = conn
   .CommandText = strSQL
   .CommandType = adCmdText

   ' BIND PARAMS TO QMARK POSITIONAL PLACEHOLDER
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("mydate", adDate, adParamInput, , dateVar)

   ' PASS RESULT TO RECORDSET
   Set rs = .Execute
End With

Sheet5.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```