# Use date in Excel cell in BETWEEN clause in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

**(1) Table [DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5d764a8e29708e57fba3dcbcdbfe139f)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int primary key,
    Product VARCHAR(255),
    insert_timestamp Date
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(id, product, insert_timestamp
)
VALUES 
("1", "Product_A", "2020-02-24 18:15:48"),
("2", "Product_B", "2020-02-24 20:30:17"),
("3", "Product_C", "2020-02-24 23:54:58"),
("4", "Product_D", "2020-02-25 08:09:30"),
("5", "Product_E", "2020-02-25 10:17:15");
```

**(2) VBA** 
Value in `Cell B1 = 2020-02-24`

```
Sub Get_Data()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim dateVar As Date

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=bi; UID=username; PWD=password; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

                strSQL = " SELECT " & _
                            " cID " & _
                            " FROM logistics " & _
                            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) BETWEEN """ & Format(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "00:00:00" & """ " & _
                            " AND """ & Format(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "23:59:59" & """ " & _
                            " GROUP BY 1 "


    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

I want to run a query within the `VBA` that uses the date in `Cell B1` within the `BETWEEN` statement in the `WHERE` clause. 
When I run this query outside of the `VBA` it works perfectly:

```
SELECT
Product
FROM logistics
WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) BETWEEN "2020-02-24 00:00:00" AND "2020-02-24 23:59:59";
```

Once, I run it in the `VBA` it does not give me an error but it also does not give me any result. 
I assume the issue is caused by my combination of the `sql` and the `VBA` in the `strSQL`.

How do I have to change the `VBA` to make it work?

Comment: While the accepted answer is working, you should invest some time in learning how to use `ADODB.Parameter` and `ADODB.Command` to pass parameters to a query. No more hassle with formatting, no issues with differences in databases (your example will not work with Oracle) and a protection against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a space between the date and the time...

Open your VBE and debug print the formula to see the result (maker sure you have the immediate window [view menu / Immediate window).

```
Sub test()
   Debug.Print Format(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "23:59:59"
End Sub
```

**result**
2020-03-1123:59:59

Just can add the space after the DD as follow

```
Format(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD ") & "23:59:59"
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or avoid using `BETWEEN` and run the less than operator: `<` without the need of `23:59:59` concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of formatting values like dates or strings into the SQL command, it is much better to use `ADODB.Parameter` - in that case the driver will do all the work for you. You don't have to take care about quotes around a string, formatting a date so that the database understands it correctly (which is highly depending on database, regional settings and so on). Plus it is a protection against SQL injection. Plus, the query optimizer can do it's job much better because it gets the same SQL command every time and remembers the execution plan.

Drawback: code get's slightly more complicated because you have to involve a `ADODB.command` object.

In your SQL statement, you put a simple `?` at the place where you want to have a parameter. You just have to take care that the numbers and the position of `?` and parameters matches.

```vb
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command, param As ADODB.Parameter, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Conn.Open "<your connection string>"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT cID FROM logistics WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY 1"

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , Date)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , Date + 1)
cmd.Parameters.Append param

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name, rs(0).Value
```

P.S. Was a little lazy for the date handling, if you have data exactly at midnight, you would get too much data.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've accepted an answer and it's a perfectly good one. I'm just leaving this here as an alternative method which you might find useful in other cases too:

```
Dim date_to_use As String

date_to_use = Format(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")

strSQl = " SELECT " & _
            " cID " & _
            " FROM logistics " & _
            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) BETWEEN '[date to use] 00:00:00'" & _
            " AND '[date to use] 23:59:59'" & _
            " GROUP BY 1 "

strSQl = Replace(strSQl, "[date to use]", date_to_use)
```

Storing the contents of `B1` in this way before using it also allows you to apply other changes to it - just in case you wanted to clean it up further or reduce the chances of SQL injection being used..