# Use ADODB.Parameter to get values between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

**(1)** Table [**DB-Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5d764a8e29708e57fba3dcbcdbfe139f):

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int primary key,
    Product VARCHAR(255),
    insert_timestamp Date
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(id, product, insert_timestamp
)
VALUES 
("1", "Product_A", "2020-02-24 18:15:48"),
("2", "Product_B", "2020-02-24 20:30:17"),
("3", "Product_C", "2020-02-24 23:54:58"),
("4", "Product_D", "2020-02-25 08:09:30"),
("5", "Product_E", "2020-02-25 10:17:15");
```

**(2)** VBA

```
Sub Get_Data()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, _
cmd As New ADODB.Command, _
param As ADODB.Parameter, _
rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=bi; UID=username; PWD=password; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

            cmd.CommandText = " SELECT Product " & _
                            " FROM logistics " & _
                            " WHERE DATE(insert_timestamp) BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY 1"

    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , "2020-02-24 00:00:00")
    cmd.Parameters.Append param
    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , "2020-02-24 23:59:59")
    cmd.Parameters.Append param

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

    heet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

With the above script I am trying to get data from the table `logistics`. 
I want to use `ADODB.Parameter` as suggested in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639194/use-date-in-excel-cell-in-between-clause-in-sql-query). 
However, with the above code I get `runtime error '-2147217900 (80040e14)'` on `Set rs = cmd.Execute`.

What do I need to change in my `VBA` to make it work?

Comment: `"2020-02-24 00:00:00"` is a string, not a date. Try `CDate("2020-02-24 23:59:59")`, or `DateSerial(2020, 2, 24) + TimeSerial(23, 59, 59)`

Comment: Also, why are you re-assigning `rs` with `Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset...` as `cmd.Execute()` returns a recordest? Alternatively, don't call `Execute` but call `rs.Open cmd`. See MSDN [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/168336/how-to-open-ado-connection-and-recordset-objects).

Comment: Also, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639194/use-date-in-excel-cell-in-between-clause-in-sql-query#comment107284462_60639384) on one of the answers in last question. Don't use `BETWEEN` if you want to exclude bounds. Use `>=` and `<` and avoid time parts.