# How to pass VBA string into SQL Server ADODB query?

Tags: sql-server, vba

VBA string to SQL works for 'WHERE from other non-date column'

I've tried several attempts: CAST in query, converting both to integers, etc.

Query returns a 0 or first few columns sometimes are the date range for all rows when running in VBA, but when pasting the VBA SQL string into SQL, it works.

```vb
    'datecol is type Date in SQL

    Dim conn as ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strdate, sqldate as String

    strdate = "11/10/20"
    sqldate = "SELECT * FROM dbTable1 WHERE datecol = '" & strdate & "'"; 

    Set rs = conn.Execute(sqldate)
    arrayRows = rs.GetRows
    rs.Close
    arrayRowsTranspose = Application.Transpose(arrayRows)
```

Comment: Use ADDB.Parameter to pass variables to a query, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/60640185/7599798 . Just be aware that a `Date` may contain a Time-part.

Comment: Thank you for the idea!  I'm not sure if I'm converting w the ADDB.Parameter correctly.  Do you mind posting how the code would change using the ADDB.Parameter method?  Thanks!

Comment: More or less Cut&Paste the code from the link. Be aware that you need to create a ADODB.command object. And you need to know if your dates in the database have a Time-Part or not. If not, it is sufficient to create only one parameter

Answer (score 0):

Probably date format is not correct, try it this way

```
strdate = "2020-11-10"
```